# PuPHPet Vagrant Debian - Installing Ruby Gem but lacking write permissions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian, vagrant, puphpet

When running `gem install homesick` I get

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547 directory.
```

This is a simple freshly created debian box using [this config.yaml](http://pastie.org/private/xsi0tyvd2uo42i5qursjvg).

I can install gems using `sudo`, but [homesick](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick) needs to be installed for the user who wants to use it (vagrant).

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've set up PuPHPet's RVM install is as a system-wide service.

If you require gems to be installed locally, might I suggest installing RVM locally as well?